# What could be said about $\Gamma(2n)=\Gamma(n)^n$?

Tags: number-theory, gamma-function

How do you solve
$$\Gamma(2n)=\Gamma(n)^n$$
The trivial solution is of course $n=1$, but there is another one according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%282n%29%3DGamma%28n%29%5En) and it gives the numerical approximation

$$n ≈ 0.323782241917058...$$

How would one solve for the two solutions? The equation is a bit arbitrary and there's probably not a closed-form for the second solution, but I just want to see...maybe there is?

I doubt that it helps, but I tried to take the natural logarithm on both sides so we get:

\begin{align} \ln(\Gamma(2n)) &= \ln(\Gamma(n)^n) \\\\ & = n\ln(\Gamma(n))\end{align}

...but I don't know how to take it from here. Maybe use some series representation for $\ln\Gamma(n)$?

Comment: Bertrand postulate

Comment: @reuns Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Bertrand postulate says that for $n>3$ there exists a prime $p$ such that $n<p<2n-2$. Thus this $p$ is a divisor of the LHS of youe eq, but not of the RHS, so the equation has no solutions for $n>3$.  It remains to check $n=1,2,3$.

Comment: @Vahe Thanks for explaining.

Comment: After Bertrand's postulate the cases of fractional n need to be considered?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Yeah, my question was to find the second solution and Bertrand's postulate doesn't really seem to help for that, or can you also consider fractional values with Bertrand's postulate?

Comment: @CasimirRönnlöf - no; Bertrand's postulate is about primes which are integer. I find it a nice idea how to disprove your question for integers this way. But for the reals/complex numbers I don't have an idea, I'm not very familiar with the gamma function ... However, the real case might be solved by looking at the curve of $\text{lngamma}(2 n)-n \cdot \text{lngamma}(n)$ and observing that $\ln(2n-1)+\ln(2n-2)+...+\ln(n) > n\cdot \ln(n) $ for some small $n$... (maybe I should write $n-1$ instead of $n$ I'm always confusing the replacing of $\Gamma(1+x)$ by $x !$... )